# Как взаимодействовать с внешними программами на python?

Tags: python

Хотел бы поднять вопрос взаимодействия python скриптов с внешними программами с целью автоматизации рутинных действий. Например нам надо много раз выполнить одну и ту же последовательность действий(мы чистим 100 пк используя специальную прогу или чистим один пк много раз: запускаем скрипт -> он открывает нужную программу-> нажимает нужные кнопки в нужной последовательности по кулдаунк окончанию процессов -> закрывает прогу). Хотелось бы узнать возможно ли и если да, то ка реализовать что то подобное не затрагивая RPA!!! Если на питоне подобное реализовать не получится, то на чем лучше и проще всего?
Буду признателен за любую помощь

Comment: `pywinauto` возможно поможет вам. Так же есть программа для **windows, powerautomate**, в которой можно автоматизировать некоторые процессы (их много), без знаний программирования.